# Override url and parse in Backbone collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, model-view-controller, backbone.js

I want to override the collection for development purpose (return fake json results from a JSON var or JSON file). But I got error doing below with `url`

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/uZhM8/

```
GET http://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/[object%20Object],[object%20Object] 404 (NOT FOUND)
```

However, if I use `parse`, it seems the `parse` got executed right after `initialize` because of both my `console.log` results show the same thing

http://jsfiddle.net/qhoc/uZhM8/1/

**So how to override the `url` so that fetch can add another JSON at some point (in separate function)?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`url` of a collection](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-url) is supposed to return a URL which will be used with `$.ajax` to talk to the server:

> **url** `collection.url` or `collection.url()`
>
> Set the **url** property (or function) on a collection to reference its location on the server. Models within the collection will use **url** to construct URLs of their own.

Your `url` method is returning an array and Backbone is treating that like a URL string, hence the odd looking URL that produces your 404.

You have some options:

- Use a URL that uses [jsfiddle's AJAX stubbing](http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/echo.html) tools to produce the necessary JSON.
- Override [`sync`](http://backbonejs.org/#Sync) to use some inlined JSON instead of a `$.ajax` call.
- Override [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) to use some inlined JSON instead of calling `sync`.

If you're only concerned about fetching data then all three should work, if you need to simulate saves or deletes, then you'll probably end up overriding `sync`.